# Livewire 404: GET http://localhost/livewire/livewire.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm learning how to use livewire and laravel, I was trying to bind some data through an input
I wrote this code:

home.blade.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>

    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    @livewire("hello-world")

    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

hello-world.blade.php:

```
<div>
    <input wire:model="nome" type="text">
    <br>
    Hello {{ $nome }}
</div>
```

HelloWorld.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class HelloWorld extends Component
{
    public $nome = 'Name';
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hello-world');
    }
}
```

It is running on Apache 2.4
But if I open the browser console when I load the page I get:

```
(index):29 GET http://localhost/livewire/livewire.js?id=c1db26b321e994f87254 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

(index):35 Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined
    at (index):35
```

I'm following official docs and screencasts, I tried to follow step-by-step all the instructions but it didin't work either.
Maybe I did something wrong during installation, but I don't think so, because I just ran `composer require livewire/livewire` so it should be ok.

Comment: what post your application is running .?

Comment: Please can you copy and paste the code in to your question rather than linking to it.

Comment: Sorry I accidently posted an incomplete question. What do you mean with "What post is your app running?"?

Comment: Ok sir, I posted it. @Rwd

Comment: What version of Livewire are you using?

Comment: If you need it I can make a repo on gitHub so you can go through all the files of the project

Comment: I'm using Livewire v. 2.1

Comment: With what URL are you accessing your project? `http://localhost`?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue can you please tell me how to solve this issue...?

Answer (score 19):

may you can try this:

run: `php artisan livewire:publish`

then open **config/livewire.php**
change `'asset_url' => null` to `'asset_url' => 'http://localhost'`

Comment: If you are running multiple projects use 'http://localhost/projectFolder/public' worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I was going through the same challenge ... please do this to sort you out.
run

```
php artisan livewire:publish
```

Open the **config/livewire.php**
edit the line

```
'asset_url' => null
```

to read

```
'asset_url' => 'http://localhost/your_project/public/',
```

run the artisan commands to clear the cache and then test. You could copy from here if you are using Linux.

```
php artisan cache:clear;php artisan config:clear;php artisan route:clear;php artisan view:clear;
```

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 4):

let dive deep in and find the solution
**your request url** you can check from your network tab

> GET http://localhost/livewire/livewire.js net::ERR_ABORTED

1. your base url

> GET http://localhost/

it should be as

> GET http://localhost/your_project_directory

2. now correct url

> GET http://localhost/your_project_directory/livewire/livewire.js

or

> GET http://localhost/your_project_directory/public/livewire/livewire.js

***Solution:***

app/config/livewire.php

> 'asset_url'  =>  env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

also update the APP_URL accordingly in .env file

you should clear your **cache** and **config**
then try I hope this will be fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by Zenabus.dev is listed in the Livewire docs as best practice now, I felt this is only a workaround and does not make clear why this is needed, so I thought I'd elaborate on this a bit and describe what a common reason for the 404 may be and what other options you have.

By default, Livewire registers a route for livewire/livewire.js and requires the request for that URL to go through the Laravel routing. The LivewireJavaScriptAssets controller will then pull the file from the vendor directory and serve it to the user.

If everything worked fine on the dev system and stops working on production like it did for me, chances are that your server / vhost configuration (Apache, Nginx, ...) has a special handling set for Javascript files which will interfere with this process and will try to serve those files directly from your document root, effectively bypassing Laravel.

Please check your server configuration and make sure [www.yourapp.com/livewire/livewire.js](http://www.yourapp.com/livewire/livewire.js) is actually routed through Laravel (via the public/index.php file).

If it is not, you can either remove any special handling of js files, make sure the rules are only applied if the files actually exist or if you cannot do either, you can resort to publishing the assets as described in https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation#publish-assets.

As a side node, I would personally not add the publish command on post-autoload-dump as described in the docs, but rather on post-update-cmd. I am not comfortable with the assets being published on the production server and would rather do this on the dev system only when needed, and then push the public files to the repository.

Answer (score 3):

In my case what wepe commented worked, only that instead of `'asset_url' => 'http://localhost'` i put `'asset_url' => url('/')`

Comment: Edit: This doesn't work in production, better to use the full path in development mode

Comment: Thanks! Worked for Laravel 8 as well :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had an nginx server that was set to cache and deliver static files like .css and .js and whenever I tried to access a route that had .js then the nginx was trying to find if the file existed and if not, to deliver a 404 error code and prevented laravel to do his thing.

The nginx setting was like this:

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
10         expires 1M;
11         access_log off;
12         add_header Cache-Control "public";
13     }
```

And i removed the `|js`.

Comment: Just to say that this is the ideal place to start when trying to solve this issue. Make sure the server is set up to serve the files and work from there. You can run any artisan command you like but if nginx isn't going to play nicely, you're stumped no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will publish the assets to your `public` folder and should solve the 404 issue.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets
```

The `@livewireScripts` blade directive is still required, but it automatically correctly fetches the assets from `/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js`

Comment: This fetches the asset the the livewire.js is still missing, i have the livewire.js.map file instead

Answer (score 2):

In livewire 3 you can register route and assets like this in `web.php` file

```
use Livewire\Livewire;

Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::post('/custom/livewire/update', $handle);
});
```

Now, instead of using `/livewire/update`, Livewire will send component updates to `/custom/livewire/update`.

same you can configure assets url

```
Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::get('/custom/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
});
```

Now, Livewire will load its JavaScript like so:

```
<script src="/custom/livewire/livewire.js" />
```

for more information read this [installation guide](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/installation)

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan livewire:publish` does NOT throw an error, if the current user does not have permissions to copy the files.

So the public/vendor/livewire folder was missing even after the livewire publish command said it had created it.

1. Fixing my permissions and
2. re-running `php artisan livewire:publish`

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also has the same problem in Livewire 3 and i fixed it. Don't know whether its a right method or not. But i will share you.

After installing Liveware 3, just navigate to

> vendor/livewire/livewire

there you can see a folder named 'dist' just copy the folder and paste it inside the Laravel public folder. After, rename the 'dist' folder inside the public folder to livewire. Inside the folder you can see the livewire.js file. This worked for me...

Answer (score -1):

I am learning Laravel Livewire too and I also encountered the same problem.
My problem was solved by running

`php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets`

You can refer to this link on github: [Problem loading Livewire.js](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/242)

Comment: [Already suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133600/1255289)

Answer (score -1):

I am using Xampp with PHP8. I had to modify the **config/livewire.php** like below:

```
'asset_url' => config('app.url').'/public',
```

where `config('app.url')` refers to: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')`, in my `config/app.php` file, that internally refers to: `APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel` in my `.env` file.

Answer (score -1):

In config/livewire.php file

```
'asset_url' => url('/'),
```